# Tokenizing without breaking up key phrases

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I have a string of text like `s = 'hi, welcome to grade 3'`

currently when I tokenize the string I get

`tokens = ['hi', 'welcome', 'to', 'grade', '3']`

How can I tokenize the string without generating separate tokens for common phrases like 'grade 3'

I would want the output to be something like

`tokens = ['hi', 'welcome', 'to', 'grade 3']`

I have a list of common phrases I want to keep in one token if that makes it simpler

Ultimately I don't want to make all of my tokens bigrams as I still need the single word tokens for other parts of the program

Comment: There are multiple ways to supply a list of phrases to NLTK.  Please post the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), showing what you used, and how it didn't work.

Comment: So the only way I could think of to get it to work is to create a completely separate function that tokenizes the sentences into bigrams and then compares with a list. 

It seems very inefficient as I am running functions to tokenize words and then a completely separate one to tokenize the bigrams.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: "only way I could think of" is only a start.  See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  Handling a lexicon of specific phrases is available with a little browser searching; I'm not sure which might work for you, as I use a different parsing tool, with better facilities for "compound nouns".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses `MWETokenizer`.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import MWETokenizer
tk = MWETokenizer([('grade', '3')])
tokens = tk.tokenize(word_tokenize('hi, welcome to grade 3'))
words = [val.replace('_', ' ') for val in tokens]
print(words)
```